# How did Skynet avoid destroying itself on Judgment Day?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

It seems at the end of Terminator 3, Skynet relies upon the connected computer network in order to have the intelligence that it has. This made it resistant to any single point of failure to destroy the network.

However, it seems it would make it very vulnerable to a thermo-nuclear war. So far as I know, most server farms (Cyber Centers) are located near major population centers.

It seems highly unlikely that there would be much of Skynet left after a major thermo-nuclear war, because most of the servers would be destroyed, and the links between them would also be destroyed.

Thus, it seems quite unlikely that there could be much left in the way of Skynet. And I'm not even beginning to touch on the subject of EMP, which as the Russians launched their nukes independent of Skynet, would likely have been detonated over the United States and allies, and possibly the world.

**How did Skynet then manage to execute Judgment Day, while still retaining enough computers and network to survive?**

Comment: Not an answer because pure conjecture; What if it launched only (or mostly) [Neutron bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_bomb), thereby killing biologic life but not infrastructure? (And the server farms were protected from the radiation ... because of reasons?)

Comment: actually a lot of data centers these days are locating in slightly less urban population centers, closer to power sources and in cooler places (to lower cost of cooling the center)

Comment: basically Skynet did chemo therapy for it's new body -- the earth's computer systems -- damaging some of it badly, but critically damaging the cancerous humanity in the process.

Comment: An even bigger problem would be power. Power stations would no longer function more than a few days (or even a few hours) without human maintenance. What would Skynet have to repair/maintain the power grid, when the only physical manipulators it had were military drones?

Comment: @vsz  That is easy enough to explain.  One of the military drones enters the power station, points a gun at the closest person still alive and states "Fix the problem or I kill you".

Comment: I'm going to call server farms "Cyber Centers" from now on

Comment: http://www.cyberbunker.com/web/index.php - This would easily survive a nuke

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some points:

- Short lengths of wire are unaffected by EMP so long as they are not part of a closed circuit.  The car that is entirely shut down electrically should still work after an EMP.
- Optical fiber and satellite based communications are immune to EMP, as are cables laid along the ocean floor.
- Server farms are beginning to recognize the benefit of having not only back-up server farms, but back-ups in locations that are remote from the main servers and sometimes in relatively small urban centers.
- Skynet was effectively software, so it could 'hide out' on any server in any location big enough for the code, or with parts of itself stored on different servers, with duplicate copies stored to check for errors (bits flipped when radiation hits the drive).  I suspect that during the worst parts of the conflict, it backed up its major components to machines in ..Australia, India, Argentina, Chile..  Those countries might be allies of one of the major combatants, but they would probably get a lot less bombs hurled their way.

Comment: "Server farms are beginning to recognize the benefit of having not only back-up server farms, but back-ups in locations that are remote from the main servers and sometimes in relatively small urban centers." And I think it's reasonable to suggest that military server farms are probably protected as well.

Comment: Skynet might just as well have waited a couple of seconds with wiping out each continent sequentially, giving themselves probably enough time to transfer their data to servers that were rebooted just at the right time...

Comment: India would be a bad choice.  They and Pakistan have nukes, and would LOVE to use them.  A widespread nuclear exchange would be a perfect excuse/opportunity for doing so.  They would annihilate each other in a heartbeat.

Comment: @Zommuter - if I recall correctly, the T-800 in T2 said Skynet launched our nukes at Russia, not at every continent.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I am from India and hearing that less bombs will be hurled at us is bit comforting. lol

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri  Sometimes it's nice to live in the 'small country towns' (the less aggressive countries of the planet). :)  I live in Australia, which although 'out of the way' of the large scale conflicts, is also a really good ally of the US.  I suspect that would put us 'back in the hot seat' as far as any global conflict went.  :(

Answer (score 24):

In addition, you have:

- Military hardware that is [EMP-shielded](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/771997.pdf) and/or emplaced to be safe from the blast (see the base John Connor is in).
- Internet grew out of ARPANET which was designed as a DARPA project **specifically aimed to ensure network resilience in the face of widescale destruction**.

Comment: The US military definitely had EMP-hardened equipment and facilities, I've worked in some. I've heard about the ARPANET being designed to survive an attack, but I've also then heard that it was just an urban myth. Personally I love the idea and hope it's true!

Comment: @MarkAllen: It's a myth; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET#Misconceptions_of_design_goals

Comment: @MartinSchröder I figured as much. I still prefer the myth. :) Thanks for the link though!